# What are the good practise for storing document with sensitive data

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My question is what are the good practise's to store document with sensitive data that might need encryption.

> Few thoughts that I have are: 1) Store all document in Sql Server as
>   FILESTREAM (don't know the drawback's of it. 2) Use one of these NoSql
>   Db. But then how safe it will be to keep documents with sensitive data.
>   3) Simple way upload them and store them on disk for every customer
>   with security.
>
> The technology I will be using is xUnit, ASP.NET
>   MVC 4, C#, Web API, Entitty Framework and Sql Server 2012

Any idea's or opinions will be highly appreciated

Comment: You want to encrypt the data on the server?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Yes, document might need encryption for they might have sensitive data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the way you **store** the data is less important, as long as the data stored in the correct way. It doesn't matter if you use SQL Server (btw, if your data is less than 2GB you can use varbinary(max) which is limited to 2GB and store the data in that column). What matters is the following things:

1. You choose the right encryption algorithm - you can choose between Symmetric encryption and Asymmetric encryption algorithms.
2. You save and protect the encryption key.  There is no much value for the encryption if somebody can just get the key easily.

After you have encrypted stream - it doesn't really matter if you'll store it in NoSQL DB, SQL Server or file on the filesystem - choose whatever is best for your app. if you already use SQL Server - then save the encrypted data in it.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server allows you to encrypt data using TDE. Here's an [`overview on MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Encryption or username password protection. It depends on how secure it needs to be. In my opinion username and password (themselves encrypted) should do.